# Error in bq load : Failed to retrieve starting URI

Tags: google-bigquery

bq load fails to load a new table. The same command was working in the sane instance.... maybe a temporary error?

thanks!

Here is some stack:

```
Network connection problem encountered, please try again.

If this problem persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client. Google engineers monitor and answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag google-bigquery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well as the following information:

========================================
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.6.6:Linux-3.3.8-gcg-201308121035-x86_64-with-centos-6.4-Final
== bq version ==
  v2.0.14
== Command line ==
  ['/usr/bin/bq', 'load', 'abracadabra.ESPChr10', '10.bigT.gz', 'header.json']
== UTC timestamp ==
  2013-11-28 18:22:08
== Error trace =

Unexpected exception in load operation: Failed to retrieve starting URI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the case sensitive for "float" in schema file. The correct way was FLOAT.

I suggest using "bq load" from your source from google storage, because the returning errors are much more intuitive.